# Matlab - Matrix Differential Equations [ Update matrix values? ]

Tags: matlab, matrix, differential-equations

Good day. I am interested in solving a problem of the form:

x_dot = Ax + F,

using Matlab. Usage of a numerical solver ( ode23/ode45) seems straightforward, but in my case the matrix A and vector F are state dependent. Thus, i need to update them after each iteration step using the newly derived state.

Can it actually be done using ode23/ode45? Do i need to follow another path?

Thanks in advance, any insight appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us what the updates to A and F are? If they are linear, you should be able to "re-arrange" this into a single, larger matrix differential equation.

Comment: in other words, what is A_dot and F_dot as a function of x and t?

Comment: It is possible. `ode45` solves non-stiff differential equation in the form `x'(t) = f(t,x)`, and your problem fits the description. Type `doc ode45` in your Command Window for details.

Comment: Sanjay Manohar, the problem is highly non linear. The equation was derived after application of finite element analysis on a structure, thus derivatives of A and F cannot be described analytically. Thanks for taking time to review/answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem fits the description of `ode45` quite well. For example, take the following meaningless equations, and numerically solve the system for t = [0,1], x(0) = (1,1):

```
    A = @(t,x) [       x(2),    exp(-t)  ; ...
                  exp(-2*t),       x(1)  ];

    F = @(t,x) [   -0.1*x(2)  ; ...
                 sin(2*pi*t)  ];

    [t_out, x_out] = ode45(@(t,x) A(t,x)*x + F(t,x), 0:0.01:1, [1;1]);

    figure();
    plot(t_out,x_out(:,1), '-b');
    hold on;
    plot(t_out,x_out(:,2), '-r');
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. The problem i am dealing with is highly non linear, and it is a multi - level structure in terms of functions, but will try to work the way you proposed.

Comment: @ParaskevasDimitris I'm not sure what multi-level means (are you talking about functions that call functions that call other functions?) but all the elements are there: the system is non-linear in terms of `x` and is non-homogeneous, the only requirement for the ODE is to be explicit (i.e. to be solved in terms of x'). The way you construct `A` and `F` are syntactical issues. But, as soon as you offer details on that too, the example can become more specific. Is up to you.

Comment: Yes that is actually the case. Thanks for your time / insight, much appreciated.